# Source Generator not seeing classes in same project

Tags: c#, sourcegenerators

I have a Source Generator, it looks like this:

```
public class Generator : ISourceGenerator
{

    public Generator()
    {
        // Uncomment if you want to debug this
        Debugger.Launch();
    }
    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterForSyntaxNotifications(() => new MySyntaxReceiver());
    }

    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        var syntaxReceiver = (MySyntaxReceiver)context.SyntaxReceiver;

        var responseMessageClasses = syntaxReceiver.ResponseMessageClasses;
        // do stuff to responseMessageClasses
    }
}

internal class MySyntaxReceiver : ISyntaxReceiver
{
    public List<ClassDeclarationSyntax> ResponseMessageClasses { get; private set; } = new List<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();

    public void OnVisitSyntaxNode(SyntaxNode syntaxNode)
    {
        if (syntaxNode is ClassDeclarationSyntax cds &&
            cds.Identifier.ValueText.EndsWith("ResponseMessage", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            ResponseMessageClasses.Add(cds);
        }
    }
}
```

In the same project, I have a folder of simple classes of which the name all ends with "ResponseMessage". These classes only have simple types like string, int and bool as properties. They are in a different namespace than the SourceGenerator.

There's a second console app project that references my source generator as an Analyzer. When I build the project I can succesfully break into the SourceGenerator code.

The problem: the simple ResponseMessage classes never get seen by the SyntaxReceiver class I have.  The `OnVisitSyntaxNode` method only hits the Program.cs file. What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design, it's not possible to use a source generator in the assembly where it was defined. According to [the design spec](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.md#implementation):

> Generator implementations are defined in external assemblies passed to the compiler using the same `-analyzer:` option used for diagnostic analyzers.
>
> ...
>
> Since generators are loaded from external assemblies, a generator cannot be used to build the assembly in which it is defined.

Comment: Yes! I realized this as well, but forgot to answer my own question. Thanks!